# how do I plot this surfaces in 2-D?

Tags: plotting

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two real numbers and define the column vector $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,x_2]$. Let $\mathbf{A}_1$ and $\mathbf{A}_2$ be two $2\times 2$ real symmetric matrices. Then I need to plot the surfaces 
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}_1\mathbf{x}+1 &\leq 0 \\
\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{A}_2\mathbf{x}+1 &\leq 0
\end{align}

How do I do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Please try to write _some_ code.

Comment: @belisarius I really want to and I understand it is inappropriate to ask without trying. I come from a matlab & engineering background and doing this in matlab is a pain. Just started with mathematica 2 hrs back.

Comment: Well, you've a kickstart below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[84];
a = # + Transpose@# &@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];
RegionPlot[{x, y}.a.{x, y} > 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1, but the condition is $x^TAx+1\le0$, not $x^TAx>0$.

Comment: @RahulNarain Nobody is perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

Using **V10** functionality and borrowing from Belisarius:

```
SeedRandom[84]
a = # + Transpose@# &@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2}];
```

We create an `ImplicitRegion`

```
region = ImplicitRegion[First[{x, y}.a.{{x}, {y}}] > 0, {x, y}];
```

And discretize it:

```
DiscretizeRegion[region, {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want `Frame`:

```
Show[%, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]